# castle monorails no simultaneous requests from the same user

Tags: fiddler, castle-monorail, session-state

I have created an website in Castle Monorails and the users that are using the site are complaining that it is very slow so I have done some investigations with fiddler and I discovered that the requests (from the same user) are not simultaneous.
I have tried to use  but it is not working and it seams that Castle monorail does not support this.
Do you have any suggestions/solutions/workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess: you're loading *all* the javascript files included in MonoRail (`$Ajax.InstallScripts()`, `$Scriptaculous.InstallScripts()`, etc) at the top of your main layout. [Javascript blocks](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/) and these scripts in particular are pretty big so the slowdown gets very noticeable.

If this is not the case, post more information, like fiddler screenshots, MonoRail version.

In any case, it's very unlikely that the problem is caused by MonoRail.

Comment: :-) yes you are somehow right... 
I include
$AjaxHelper.GetJavascriptFunctions()
dumb question how to include the script to resolve this problem?

Comment: remove the scripts you don't need, see http://betterexplained.com/articles/speed-up-your-javascript-load-time/ or create another, more specific question